# MiKTeX makepk did not succeed

Tags: miktex, miktex2.9

I have stable code that always ran with MiKTeX. The last successful version I installed was MiKTeX 2.9.7269-x64. However today I uninstalled MiKTeX and installed 2.9.7342-x64 (with all pending updates). A full uninstall followed by a clean new install always worked before. My environment is Winodws 10 Pro, current version.

When running my application (which was working fine all day with 2.9.7269-x64) I am always prompted for:

[image]

and the console always ends with the following:

[image]

The log file is here (apologies for the length):

```
2019-11-21 19:53:12,306+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - starting with command line: miktex-makepk --verbose cmsy7 600 600 magstep(0.0) ljfour
2019-11-21 19:53:12,308+0100 INFO  makepk - Trying to make PK font cmsy7 at 600 DPI...
2019-11-21 19:53:12,326+0100 INFO  makepk - Creating cmsy7.pk...
2019-11-21 19:53:12,330+0100 INFO  makepk - Running miktex-mf.exe...
2019-11-21 19:53:12,330+0100 INFO  makepk - running: miktex-mf.exe --miktex-disable-maintenance --undump=mf \mode:=ljfour; \mag:=magstep(0.0); nonstopmode; "input cmsy7"
2019-11-21 19:53:13,540+0100 INFO  makepk - Running miktex-gftopk.exe...
2019-11-21 19:53:13,542+0100 INFO  makepk - running: miktex-gftopk.exe --miktex-disable-maintenance cmsy7.600gf cmsy7.pk
2019-11-21 19:53:13,766+0100 INFO  makepk - Installing C:\Users\Andrew\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts/pk/ljfour/public/cm/dpi600\cmsy7.pk...
2019-11-21 19:53:13,776+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - finishing with exit code 0
2019-11-21 19:53:14,039+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - starting with command line: miktex-makepk --verbose phvb8r 600 600 magstep(0.0) ljfour
2019-11-21 19:53:14,039+0100 INFO  makepk - Trying to make PK font phvb8r at 600 DPI...
2019-11-21 19:53:14,053+0100 INFO  makepk - Running miktex-makemf.exe...
2019-11-21 19:53:14,053+0100 INFO  makepk - running: miktex-makemf.exe --miktex-disable-maintenance --verbose phvb8r
2019-11-21 19:53:14,289+0100 INFO  makepk - Running miktex-ttf2pk.exe...
2019-11-21 19:53:14,289+0100 INFO  makepk - running: miktex-ttf2pk.exe --miktex-disable-maintenance -q -t phvb8r
2019-11-21 19:53:42,100+0100 INFO  makepk - Creating phvb8r.pk...
2019-11-21 19:53:42,100+0100 INFO  makepk - Running gsf2pk.exe...
2019-11-21 19:53:42,100+0100 INFO  makepk - running: gsf2pk.exe --miktex-disable-maintenance phvb8r NimbusSanL-Bold "TeXBase1Encoding ReEncodeFont" 8r.enc uhvb8a.pfb 600 phvb8r.pk
2019-11-21 19:53:42,190+0100 FATAL miktex-makepk - GSF2PK failed on uhvb8a.pfb.
2019-11-21 19:53:42,192+0100 FATAL miktex-makepk - GSF2PK failed on uhvb8a.pfb.
2019-11-21 19:53:42,192+0100 FATAL miktex-makepk - Info: 
2019-11-21 19:53:42,192+0100 FATAL miktex-makepk - Source: 
2019-11-21 19:53:42,192+0100 FATAL miktex-makepk - Line: 0
2019-11-21 19:53:42,208+0100 INFO  makepk - Running miktex-ps2pk.exe...
2019-11-21 19:53:42,208+0100 INFO  makepk - running: miktex-ps2pk.exe --miktex-disable-maintenance -v -X600 -e 8r.enc uhvb8a.pfb phvb8r.pk
2019-11-21 19:53:42,432+0100 INFO  makepk - Installing C:\Users\Andrew\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts/pk/modeless/adobe/helvetic/dpi600\phvb8r.pk...
2019-11-21 19:53:42,440+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - finishing with exit code 0
2019-11-21 19:53:42,692+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - starting with command line: miktex-makepk --verbose cmr8 600 600 magstep(0.0) ljfour
2019-11-21 19:53:42,694+0100 INFO  makepk - Trying to make PK font cmr8 at 600 DPI...
2019-11-21 19:53:42,712+0100 INFO  makepk - Creating cmr8.pk...
2019-11-21 19:53:42,714+0100 INFO  makepk - Running miktex-mf.exe...
2019-11-21 19:53:42,714+0100 INFO  makepk - running: miktex-mf.exe --miktex-disable-maintenance --undump=mf \mode:=ljfour; \mag:=magstep(0.0); nonstopmode; "input cmr8"
2019-11-21 19:53:43,108+0100 INFO  makepk - Running miktex-gftopk.exe...
2019-11-21 19:53:43,108+0100 INFO  makepk - running: miktex-gftopk.exe --miktex-disable-maintenance cmr8.600gf cmr8.pk
2019-11-21 19:53:43,302+0100 INFO  makepk - Installing C:\Users\Andrew\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts/pk/ljfour/public/cm/dpi600\cmr8.pk...
2019-11-21 19:53:43,312+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - finishing with exit code 0
2019-11-21 19:53:43,564+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - starting with command line: miktex-makepk --verbose cmr9 600 600 magstep(0.0) ljfour
2019-11-21 19:53:43,566+0100 INFO  makepk - Trying to make PK font cmr9 at 600 DPI...
2019-11-21 19:53:43,582+0100 INFO  makepk - Creating cmr9.pk...
2019-11-21 19:53:43,586+0100 INFO  makepk - Running miktex-mf.exe...
2019-11-21 19:53:43,586+0100 INFO  makepk - running: miktex-mf.exe --miktex-disable-maintenance --undump=mf \mode:=ljfour; \mag:=magstep(0.0); nonstopmode; "input cmr9"
2019-11-21 19:53:43,967+0100 INFO  makepk - Running miktex-gftopk.exe...
2019-11-21 19:53:43,967+0100 INFO  makepk - running: miktex-gftopk.exe --miktex-disable-maintenance cmr9.600gf cmr9.pk
2019-11-21 19:53:44,139+0100 INFO  makepk - Installing C:\Users\Andrew\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts/pk/ljfour/public/cm/dpi600\cmr9.pk...
2019-11-21 19:53:44,149+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - finishing with exit code 0
2019-11-21 19:53:44,401+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - starting with command line: miktex-makepk --verbose cmbx10 600 600 magstep(0.0) ljfour
2019-11-21 19:53:44,403+0100 INFO  makepk - Trying to make PK font cmbx10 at 600 DPI...
2019-11-21 19:53:44,419+0100 INFO  makepk - Creating cmbx10.pk...
2019-11-21 19:53:44,423+0100 INFO  makepk - Running miktex-mf.exe...
2019-11-21 19:53:44,423+0100 INFO  makepk - running: miktex-mf.exe --miktex-disable-maintenance --undump=mf \mode:=ljfour; \mag:=magstep(0.0); nonstopmode; "input cmbx10"
2019-11-21 19:53:44,809+0100 INFO  makepk - Running miktex-gftopk.exe...
2019-11-21 19:53:44,809+0100 INFO  makepk - running: miktex-gftopk.exe --miktex-disable-maintenance cmbx10.600gf cmbx10.pk
2019-11-21 19:53:44,987+0100 INFO  makepk - Installing C:\Users\Andrew\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts/pk/ljfour/public/cm/dpi600\cmbx10.pk...
2019-11-21 19:53:44,997+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - finishing with exit code 0
2019-11-21 19:53:45,247+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - starting with command line: miktex-makepk --verbose cmr10 600 600 magstep(0.0) ljfour
2019-11-21 19:53:45,249+0100 INFO  makepk - Trying to make PK font cmr10 at 600 DPI...
2019-11-21 19:53:45,263+0100 INFO  makepk - Creating cmr10.pk...
2019-11-21 19:53:45,267+0100 INFO  makepk - Running miktex-mf.exe...
2019-11-21 19:53:45,267+0100 INFO  makepk - running: miktex-mf.exe --miktex-disable-maintenance --undump=mf \mode:=ljfour; \mag:=magstep(0.0); nonstopmode; "input cmr10"
2019-11-21 19:53:45,645+0100 INFO  makepk - Running miktex-gftopk.exe...
2019-11-21 19:53:45,645+0100 INFO  makepk - running: miktex-gftopk.exe --miktex-disable-maintenance cmr10.600gf cmr10.pk
2019-11-21 19:53:45,817+0100 INFO  makepk - Installing C:\Users\Andrew\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts/pk/ljfour/public/cm/dpi600\cmr10.pk...
2019-11-21 19:53:45,825+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - finishing with exit code 0
2019-11-21 19:53:46,077+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - starting with command line: miktex-makepk --verbose cmss8 525 600 0+525/600 ljfour
2019-11-21 19:53:46,079+0100 INFO  makepk - Trying to make PK font cmss8 at 525 DPI...
2019-11-21 19:53:46,095+0100 INFO  makepk - Creating cmss8.pk...
2019-11-21 19:53:46,099+0100 INFO  makepk - Running miktex-mf.exe...
2019-11-21 19:53:46,099+0100 INFO  makepk - running: miktex-mf.exe --miktex-disable-maintenance --undump=mf \mode:=ljfour; \mag:=0+525/600; nonstopmode; "input cmss8"
2019-11-21 19:53:46,450+0100 INFO  makepk - Running miktex-gftopk.exe...
2019-11-21 19:53:46,452+0100 INFO  makepk - running: miktex-gftopk.exe --miktex-disable-maintenance cmss8.525gf cmss8.pk
2019-11-21 19:53:46,624+0100 INFO  makepk - Installing C:\Users\Andrew\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts/pk/ljfour/public/cm/dpi525\cmss8.pk...
2019-11-21 19:53:46,632+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - finishing with exit code 0
2019-11-21 19:53:46,880+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - starting with command line: miktex-makepk --verbose cmr7 600 600 magstep(0.0) ljfour
2019-11-21 19:53:46,882+0100 INFO  makepk - Trying to make PK font cmr7 at 600 DPI...
2019-11-21 19:53:46,896+0100 INFO  makepk - Creating cmr7.pk...
2019-11-21 19:53:46,900+0100 INFO  makepk - Running miktex-mf.exe...
2019-11-21 19:53:46,900+0100 INFO  makepk - running: miktex-mf.exe --miktex-disable-maintenance --undump=mf \mode:=ljfour; \mag:=magstep(0.0); nonstopmode; "input cmr7"
2019-11-21 19:53:47,280+0100 INFO  makepk - Running miktex-gftopk.exe...
2019-11-21 19:53:47,280+0100 INFO  makepk - running: miktex-gftopk.exe --miktex-disable-maintenance cmr7.600gf cmr7.pk
2019-11-21 19:53:47,452+0100 INFO  makepk - Installing C:\Users\Andrew\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts/pk/ljfour/public/cm/dpi600\cmr7.pk...
2019-11-21 19:53:47,460+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - finishing with exit code 0
2019-11-21 19:53:47,712+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - starting with command line: miktex-makepk --verbose cmr5 600 600 magstep(0.0) ljfour
2019-11-21 19:53:47,714+0100 INFO  makepk - Trying to make PK font cmr5 at 600 DPI...
2019-11-21 19:53:47,730+0100 INFO  makepk - Creating cmr5.pk...
2019-11-21 19:53:47,732+0100 INFO  makepk - Running miktex-mf.exe...
2019-11-21 19:53:47,732+0100 INFO  makepk - running: miktex-mf.exe --miktex-disable-maintenance --undump=mf \mode:=ljfour; \mag:=magstep(0.0); nonstopmode; "input cmr5"
2019-11-21 19:53:48,112+0100 INFO  makepk - Running miktex-gftopk.exe...
2019-11-21 19:53:48,112+0100 INFO  makepk - running: miktex-gftopk.exe --miktex-disable-maintenance cmr5.600gf cmr5.pk
2019-11-21 19:53:48,284+0100 INFO  makepk - Installing C:\Users\Andrew\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts/pk/ljfour/public/cm/dpi600\cmr5.pk...
2019-11-21 19:53:48,292+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - finishing with exit code 0
2020-02-13 20:21:12,966+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - starting with command line: miktex-makepk --verbose tcss0700 600 600 magstep(0.0)
2020-02-13 20:21:12,967+0100 INFO  makepk - Trying to make PK font tcss0700 at 600 DPI...
2020-02-13 20:21:21,767+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - installing package metafont triggered by metafont/misc\modes.mf
2020-02-13 20:21:23,865+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - mpm: starting package maintenance...
2020-02-13 20:21:23,867+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - mpm: installation directory: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9"
2020-02-13 20:21:23,868+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - mpm: package repository: https://packages.oth-regensburg.de/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
2020-02-13 20:21:23,869+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - mpm: visiting repository https://packages.oth-regensburg.de/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/...
2020-02-13 20:21:23,869+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - mpm: repository type: remote package repository
2020-02-13 20:21:23,869+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - mpm: loading package repository manifest...
2020-02-13 20:21:23,871+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - mpm: downloading https://packages.oth-regensburg.de/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-zzdb1-2.9.tar.lzma...
2020-02-13 20:21:24,259+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - mpm: 0.20 MB, 4.09 Mbit/s
2020-02-13 20:21:24,452+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - mpm: package repository digest: 7cfad917dccd8c1461c9592b4f9f72cd
2020-02-13 20:21:25,205+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - mpm: going to download 8754 bytes
2020-02-13 20:21:25,206+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - mpm: going to install 7 file(s) (1 package(s))
2020-02-13 20:21:25,778+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - mpm: downloading https://packages.oth-regensburg.de/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/metafont.tar.lzma...
2020-02-13 20:21:25,807+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - mpm: 0.01 MB, 2.50 Mbit/s
2020-02-13 20:21:25,814+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - mpm: extracting files from metafont.tar.lzma...
2020-02-13 20:21:28,080+0100 FATAL miktex-makepk - The installed file does not exist.
2020-02-13 20:21:28,080+0100 FATAL miktex-makepk - Info: fileName="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\metafont/misc\modes.mf"
2020-02-13 20:21:28,080+0100 FATAL miktex-makepk - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\findfile.cpp
2020-02-13 20:21:28,080+0100 FATAL miktex-makepk - Line: 59
2020-02-13 20:25:50,371+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - starting with command line: miktex-makepk --verbose tcss0700 600 600 magstep(0.0)
2020-02-13 20:25:50,371+0100 INFO  makepk - Trying to make PK font tcss0700 at 600 DPI...
2020-02-13 20:25:55,600+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - installing package metafont triggered by metafont/misc\modes.mf
2020-02-13 20:25:57,452+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - mpm: starting package maintenance...
2020-02-13 20:25:57,453+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - mpm: installation directory: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9"
2020-02-13 20:25:57,455+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - mpm: package repository: http://ftp.agdsn.de/pub/mirrors/latex/dante/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
2020-02-13 20:25:57,457+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - mpm: visiting repository http://ftp.agdsn.de/pub/mirrors/latex/dante/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/...
2020-02-13 20:25:57,458+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - mpm: repository type: remote package repository
2020-02-13 20:25:57,459+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - mpm: loading package repository manifest...
2020-02-13 20:25:57,464+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - mpm: downloading http://ftp.agdsn.de/pub/mirrors/latex/dante/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-zzdb1-2.9.tar.lzma...
2020-02-13 20:25:57,829+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - mpm: 0.20 MB, 4.39 Mbit/s
2020-02-13 20:25:57,979+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - mpm: package repository digest: 7cfad917dccd8c1461c9592b4f9f72cd
2020-02-13 20:25:58,715+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - mpm: going to download 8754 bytes
2020-02-13 20:25:58,715+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - mpm: going to install 7 file(s) (1 package(s))
2020-02-13 20:25:59,269+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - mpm: downloading http://ftp.agdsn.de/pub/mirrors/latex/dante/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/metafont.tar.lzma...
2020-02-13 20:25:59,346+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - mpm: 0.01 MB, 0.92 Mbit/s
2020-02-13 20:25:59,391+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - mpm: extracting files from metafont.tar.lzma...
2020-02-13 20:26:01,650+0100 FATAL miktex-makepk - The installed file does not exist.
2020-02-13 20:26:01,650+0100 FATAL miktex-makepk - Info: fileName="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\metafont/misc\modes.mf"
2020-02-13 20:26:01,650+0100 FATAL miktex-makepk - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\findfile.cpp
2020-02-13 20:26:01,650+0100 FATAL miktex-makepk - Line: 59
2020-02-13 20:28:11,775+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - starting with command line: miktex-makepk --verbose tcss0700 600 600 magstep(0.0)
2020-02-13 20:28:11,777+0100 INFO  makepk - Trying to make PK font tcss0700 at 600 DPI...
2020-02-13 20:28:17,205+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - installing package metafont triggered by metafont/misc\modes.mf
2020-02-13 20:28:19,151+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - mpm: starting package maintenance...
2020-02-13 20:28:19,153+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - mpm: installation directory: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9"
2020-02-13 20:28:19,154+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - mpm: package repository: http://ctan.ebinger.cc/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
2020-02-13 20:28:19,156+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - mpm: visiting repository http://ctan.ebinger.cc/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/...
2020-02-13 20:28:19,157+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - mpm: repository type: remote package repository
2020-02-13 20:28:19,158+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - mpm: loading package repository manifest...
2020-02-13 20:28:19,162+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - mpm: downloading http://ctan.ebinger.cc/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-zzdb1-2.9.tar.lzma...
2020-02-13 20:28:19,494+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - mpm: 0.20 MB, 4.81 Mbit/s
2020-02-13 20:28:19,651+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - mpm: package repository digest: 7cfad917dccd8c1461c9592b4f9f72cd
2020-02-13 20:28:20,402+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - mpm: going to download 8754 bytes
2020-02-13 20:28:20,402+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - mpm: going to install 7 file(s) (1 package(s))
2020-02-13 20:28:20,953+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - mpm: downloading http://ctan.ebinger.cc/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/metafont.tar.lzma...
2020-02-13 20:28:20,999+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - mpm: 0.01 MB, 1.59 Mbit/s
2020-02-13 20:28:21,052+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - mpm: extracting files from metafont.tar.lzma...
2020-02-13 20:28:23,302+0100 FATAL miktex-makepk - The installed file does not exist.
2020-02-13 20:28:23,302+0100 FATAL miktex-makepk - Info: fileName="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\metafont/misc\modes.mf"
2020-02-13 20:28:23,302+0100 FATAL miktex-makepk - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\findfile.cpp
2020-02-13 20:28:23,302+0100 FATAL miktex-makepk - Line: 59
2020-02-13 20:28:39,319+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - starting with command line: miktex-makepk --verbose tcss0700 600 600 magstep(0.0)
2020-02-13 20:28:39,321+0100 INFO  makepk - Trying to make PK font tcss0700 at 600 DPI...
2020-02-13 20:28:50,794+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - installing package metafont triggered by metafont/misc\modes.mf
2020-02-13 20:28:52,809+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - mpm: starting package maintenance...
2020-02-13 20:28:52,811+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - mpm: installation directory: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9"
2020-02-13 20:28:52,814+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - mpm: package repository: https://ctan.kako-dev.de/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
2020-02-13 20:28:52,818+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - mpm: visiting repository https://ctan.kako-dev.de/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/...
2020-02-13 20:28:52,820+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - mpm: repository type: remote package repository
2020-02-13 20:28:52,825+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - mpm: loading package repository manifest...
2020-02-13 20:28:52,831+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - mpm: downloading https://ctan.kako-dev.de/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-zzdb1-2.9.tar.lzma...
2020-02-13 20:28:53,159+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - mpm: 0.20 MB, 4.94 Mbit/s
2020-02-13 20:28:53,345+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - mpm: package repository digest: 7cfad917dccd8c1461c9592b4f9f72cd
2020-02-13 20:28:54,080+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - mpm: going to download 8754 bytes
2020-02-13 20:28:54,080+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - mpm: going to install 7 file(s) (1 package(s))
2020-02-13 20:28:54,632+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - mpm: downloading https://ctan.kako-dev.de/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/metafont.tar.lzma...
2020-02-13 20:28:54,657+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - mpm: 0.01 MB, 2.92 Mbit/s
2020-02-13 20:28:54,677+0100 INFO  miktex-makepk - mpm: extracting files from metafont.tar.lzma...
2020-02-13 20:28:56,968+0100 FATAL miktex-makepk - The installed file does not exist.
2020-02-13 20:28:56,968+0100 FATAL miktex-makepk - Info: fileName="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\metafont/misc\modes.mf"
2020-02-13 20:28:56,968+0100 FATAL miktex-makepk - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\findfile.cpp
2020-02-13 20:28:56,968+0100 FATAL miktex-makepk - Line: 59
```

If a MiKTeX reinstall doesn't help, I'll try installing the older version again.

**EDIT:** Installing 2.9.7269-x64 leads me to a new error that I never had with this version before:

[image]

... so I can't go back to the old version + I can't go forward either.

Comment: at first check for updates in user and admin mode and update in both mode the package database (in the menu tasks). If the problem persists you should show a small example that one can test. And stop to deinstall and reinstall miktex. This seldom solves a problem.

Comment: Okay, now it works. I reinstalled the latest version (basic-miktex-2.9.7342-x64.exe) with just one change: I did not opt for "ask me first" when a new package is required. This time I opted for "yes" (just install it). I don't know if this is highly relevant to the problem I had (I don't want to repeat with a fresh install again), however ever time I did a clean UNINSTALL, deleted any residual information in AppData (i.e. deleted the folder C:\Users\Andrew\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9) and restarted my PC before beginning a fresh install.